# AutoMapper select expression translation

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm trying to understand exactly what select expression AutoMapper will generate for the following mapping. I'm attempting to replicate a bug that only manifests when using AutoMapper projection, but does not with a handcrafted select expression. I am aware that the mapping expression is redundant and may be simplified, but then the bug vanishes as well.

I believe the mapping should generate a select expression verbatim to the following, but I know it doesn't, because by substituting that expression in instead of projecting with AutoMapper, everything works as expected (and the bug vanishes).

`dbContext.Blogs.Select(blog => new BlogDto { Post = blog.Posts.Any() ? blog.Posts.Select(post => new PostDto()).FirstOrDefault() : null })`

```
public class Blog
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty(nameof(Post.Blog))]
    public virtual List<Post> Posts { get; } = new List<Post>();
}
public class Post
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Guid BlogId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(BlogId))]
    public virtual Blog Blog { get; private set; }
}

public class BlogDto
{
    public PostDto Post { get; set; }
}
public class PostDto { }

public class BlogProfile : Profile
{
    public BlogProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Blog, BlogDto>()
            .ForMember(x => x.Post, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Posts.Any() ? y.Posts.FirstOrDefault() : null));
    }
}
public class PostProfile : Profile
{
    public PostProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Post, PostDto>();
    }
}
```

TLDR I'm trying to understand what (or how) the select expression verbatim AutoMapper will generate with the above mapping.

Comment: Check [the execution plan](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Understanding-your-mapping.html).

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thank you, seems exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Per @LucianBargaoanu 's suggestion, in order to get the precise `select` expression AutoMapper generates when using `ProjectTo<>()`, you just need to call `context.Entities.ProjectTo<Dto>().Expression.ToString()`. There was an `IIF` statement in the expression which I just translated into a ternary expression.

For the mappings posted, the output of `ToString()` was the following.

`` value(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1[EFCoreBugs.Blog]).Select(dtoBlog => new BlogDto() {Post = IIF((IIF(dtoBlog.Posts.Any(), dtoBlog.Posts.FirstOrDefault(), null) == null), null, new PostDto() {})}) ``

This will help tremendously in diagnosing/understanding more complicated query expressions.